# Multiple models generic ListView to template

Tags: django, django-views

What is the SIMPLEST method for getting 2 models to be listed in a generic IndexView? My two models are `CharacterSeries` and `CharacterUniverse`.

My views.py

```
    from .models import CharacterSeries, CharacterUniverse

    
    class IndexView(generic.ListView):
        template_name = 'character/index.html'
        context_object_name = 'character_series_list'

        def get_queryset(self):
            return CharacterSeries.objects.order_by('name')
```

I need to know the shortest and most elegant code. Looked a lot but don't want to use mixins. I am perhaps not being pointed in the right direction.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can pass the one queryset in as context on the ListView like this,

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'character/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'character_series_list'
    model = CharacterSeries

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            'character_universe_list': CharacterUniverse.objects.order_by('name'),
            'more_context': Model.objects.all(),
        })
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        return CharacterSeries.objects.order_by('name')
```

Comment: I will look at your answer; I just posted an answer to my own before reading this. Thanks. Will discuss.

Comment: My method worked without the ``context.update`` part.. Can you please explain? Thanks.

Comment: It's just personal preference, I just prefer using context.update, instead of context['value'], both methods does exactly the same.

Comment: quick question for the future. How about 3 models? Can we just use the ``get_context_data`` over and over for more models?

Comment: If you want to pass in another list of you can just add to the context. in that case I would say use the context.update method as the code will at least look cleaner. I'll update my answer to show you what I'm trying to explain.

Comment: Fantastic info; will just keep adding to the context.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81952/discussion-between-klandshome-and-pieter-hamman).

Comment: I want to do pagination on both models. Can that be accommodated?

Comment: @sureshvv - Did you arrive at a solution? I was also trying something like this.

Answer (score 9):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin.get_context_data

Sounds like a mixin is the only (right)? way. I added a `get_context_data` method and now it works.

**Quick question how about adding more than 2 models..?**

below works with the 2 models now:

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'character/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'character_series_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return CharacterSeries.objects.order_by('name')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['character_universe_list'] = CharacterUniverse.objects.order_by('name')
        return context
```