# Converting codes from FBV to CBV in Django Views

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I'm currently converting my function-based views to class-based views.  On my template, I get a value through the `input` tag.

```
<input name="search_text" type="text">
```

After getting the value, I process with the value like the following in FBV.

```
def search(request):
    search_text = request.GET.get('search_text')

    search_stores = Store.objects.filter(Q(businessName__icontains=search_text) | Q(mKey__icontains=search_text))
```

But now, I wanna convert the codes to CBV.
How can I do that?

**UPDATE**

```
def search(request):
    search_text = request.GET.get('search_text')
    sorter = request.GET.get('sorter')

    if not sorter:
        sorter = 'popularity'

    if search_text:
        search_stores = Store.objects.filter(Q(businessName__icontains=search_text) | Q(mKey__icontains=search_text))
        if sorter == 'businessName':
            search_stores = search_stores.order_by(sorter)
        else:
            search_stores = search_stores.order_by(sorter).reverse()
    else:
        search_stores = ''

    for store in search_stores:
        store.mKey = store.mKey.split(' ')

    return render(request, 'boutique/search.html', {
        'search_stores': search_stores,
        'search_text': search_text,
        'sorter': sorter,
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your solution using [ListView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview)

```
from django.views.generic import ListView

class SearchView(ListView):
     template_name = 'template.html'
     model = Store

     def get_queryset(self):
         search_text = self.kwargs['search_text']
         object_list = self.model.objects.filter(Q(businessName__icontains=search_text) | Q(mKey__icontains=search_text))
         return object_list
```

Comment: Thanks!, I have one more thing to ask. As you see the updated original post, I'm returning multiple items in the search function. How can I return multiple items in the `get_queryset` function? Can I just use the `render` function?

Comment: You can't use render in CBV. Maybe you need to use `get_context_data`,  here is a  example https://stackoverflow.com/a/31134299/2566671