# Using Muliple Model with Class based View Django 2.0

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-class-based-views

I'm building a warehouse management application in which I required to pass multiple models to class based views. For Example, I have a list of all the order with Product and fulfilment status. But I'm not able to pass multiple models form my class-based view to be displayed and use in my Template
my Order Model

```
class Order(models.Model):
    Order_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    Product = models.ManyToManyField(Product)
    Shipping_addreess_1 = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=False)
    Shipping_addreess_2 = models.CharField(max_length = 1000,blank= True)
    Shipping_addreess_3 = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    Pin_Code = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    City = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True)
    State = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False)
    Order_date = models.DateField
    Order_status = models.CharField(choices = order_status,max_length=2)
    Payment_method = models.CharField(choices = Payment_type,max_length=3)
```

my Product model

```
class Product(models.Model):
    SKU = models.CharField(max_length=365, unique=Tr)
    product_title = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank = False)
    FSN = models.CharField(max_length=365,blank=True)
    Listing_ID = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    ASIN = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    Price = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    Product_category = models.CharField(max_length=256) #poster,t-shirt,notebook

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_title
```

I try passing through `get_context_data` method. As mention in some answer here.

Views.py

```
class OrderListView(ListView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['order'] = Order.objects.all()
        context['Product'] = Product.objects.all()
        return context
```

But I got the error.

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/orders/

Django Version: 2.2
Python Version: 3.6.9
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'orders']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/home/cisco/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/cisco/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/cisco/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/cisco/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/cisco/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  97.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/cisco/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/list.py" in get
  142.         self.object_list = self.get_queryset()

File "/home/cisco/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/list.py" in get_queryset
  39.                     'cls': self.__class__.__name__

Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured at /orders/
Exception Value: OrderListView is missing a QuerySet. Define OrderListView.model, OrderListView.queryset, or override OrderListView.get_queryset().
```

So how can I do it not just in Listview but also in Detailview and Updateview

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31134299/8601641) might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a ListView, DetailView or UpdateView, you will have to set the model or the method get_queryset.

Try the following, your order objects will be available in the template with the name object_list.

```
class OrderListView(ListView):
    model = Order

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['products'] = Product.objects.all()
        return context
```

Comment: I want my Order as well as Product model in the template. In the above case, I only get the Order model in object_list. Not the Product model. I want both of them in the template.

Comment: Your Product objects would be available in the template using the variable name products.

Comment: Thanks a lot got it. Just want to know your opinion in the above case. Should I stick with Class-based view or Function-based view will be better, for this particular case

Comment: I would stick with Class-based views if you are using them in the rest of your application.