# Django ListView is missing a QuerySet - Error Message - 2 Models In 1 View

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to view data from 2 models in a single list view.  I'm getting the below error message and I can't seem to figure out why.  I have included the browser error, views.py, urls.py and html page.  Any assistance would be appreciated and as a side note I'm new to programming, Python and Django.

**Error:**
ImproperlyConfigured at /scripts/patientsdetails/
PatientListView is missing a QuerySet. Define PatientListView.model, PatientListView.queryset, or override PatientListView.get_queryset().
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/scripts/patientsdetails/
Django Version: 3.2.2
Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured
Exception Value:
PatientListView is missing a QuerySet. Define PatientListView.model, PatientListView.queryset, or override PatientListView.get_queryset().

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import (
    ScriptListView,
    ScriptUpdateView,
    ScriptDetailView,
    ScriptDeleteView,
    ScriptCreateView,
    PatientListView,
    PatientUpdateView,
    PatientDetailView,
    PatientDeleteView,
    PatientCreateView,
)
urlpatterns = [
    path('patientsdetails/', 
        PatientListView.as_view(), name='patient_list'),

]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView, DeleteView, CreateView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from bootstrap_datepicker_plus import DatePickerInput, TimePickerInput
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.shortcuts import render
from scripts.models import Patient, Script
from .models import Script, Patient

class PatientListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'patient_summary.html'
 
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PatientListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs).filter(author=self.request.user)
        context['patient'] = Patient.objects.filter(author=self.request.user)
        context['script'] = Script.objects.filter(author=self.request.user)
        return context
```

**html**

```
    {% for patient in object_list %}
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <span class="font-weight-bold">{{ patient.patient_name }}</span> &middot;
                <span class="text-muted"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                Cycle Start Date - {{ patient.cycle_start_day }} <br>
                {% endfor %}

                {% for script in object_list %}
                Drug Name - {{ script.drug_name }} <br>
                {% endfor %}
                </div>
            <div class="card-footer text-center text-muted">
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's clear from the error that you have to define which model/queryset attribute to work upon by list view
Do this in your view:

```
model = Patient
```

Or

```
queryset = Patient.objects.all()
```

Or override get_queryset method

```
def get_queryset(self):
        return Patient.objects.all()
```

Comment: Kind of makes sense to me but where I'm getting confused is if in a single view that needs to show multiple models if I go model = x then I'm locked to that single model in the view right?

Comment: Attribute defined will be your primary model and then You can override get_context_data to pass secondary model data kindly check this answer it will surely help..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31133963/multiple-models-generic-listview-to-template

Comment: Thanks so much.   The link you provided above gave me the info I was looking for.  I will post the final view here when I get all the details worked out.