# How to apply two models to one view?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have 2 models Goods and Number models and I need to apply those models to IndexView.
I would be pleased to know how this can be done in my code
sorry for english.
this is code of views.py

```
from django.views import generic
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Question
from .models import Goods
from .models import Number

class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'Homepage/index.html'
    model = Goods
    context_object_name = 'goods'

    def description(self):
        return self.description_text

    def price(self):
        return self.price_text

class NumbersView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'Homepage/index.html'
    model = Number
    context_object_name = 'numbers'

    def number1(self):
        return self.number1_text

    def number2(self):
        return self.number2_text
```

this is code of models.py

```
    class Goods(models.Model):
    description_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image_sale = models.ImageField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.image_sale

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description_text

    def __str__(self):
        return self.price_text


    class Number(models.Model):
        number1_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        number2_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.number1_text

    def __str__(self):
        return self.number2_text
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple models generic ListView to template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31133963/multiple-models-generic-listview-to-template)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'Homepage/index.html'
    model = Goods
    context_object_name = 'goods'

    def description(self):
        return self.description_text

    def price(self):
        return self.price_text

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        numbers = Number.objects.all()
        context['numbers'] = numbers
        return context
```